# why this page is marked as unsecure by firefox and chrome?

Tags: ssl, https, scripting, insecure-connection

When I load this page:
https://lnx.sinapsi.org/wordpress/giochi-didattici/matematica/
I get this warning:
"This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources"

How could I solve this issue and get a "secure page" with green locker?

Comment: You include `http://sinapsi.files.wordpress.com` as can be easily seen if you use developer tools.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, but I don't find that. How can I see using developer tools?

Comment: Moreover I fount mixed content in this: https://lnx.sinapsi.org/wordpress/2007/09/29/imparo-giocando/ but I cannot see any http://

Comment: In Chrome developer tools security overview it clearly says Mixed Content and tells you what you have to do to get more details. Just follow the instructions.